# List of apps ever downloaded

Tags: applications, google-play-store

I bought myself a new Android phone since my last one died (overheated). So I've lost all the applications.

Is there some kind of download history to find what you've downloaded via your Google Account or something? I'm aware of something similar in `Market > My Apps`,  but that contains only what you have on the current device.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I ran across this by accident, but it is *exactly* what I was after! Hope it helps others.

[**https://market.android.com/account**](https://market.android.com/account) and the **Orders** tab

**Update** - this is now **https://play.google.com/apps**

Comment: That is a nice find. it appears, at least to me, that it only shows what is currently installed. it doesn't show apps that are not installed, not free ones any how.

Comment: I regularly wipe my phones (generally because I'm putting on a new ROM) and Google keeps a backup of my current phone state which includes installed applications. When I boot into the new install it downloads them all again. If that hasn't happend (which it evidently hasn't) then I think that the information has gone and you'll have to do it from your own memory.

Comment: If this is exactly what you're looking for, don't forget to accept it.

Answer (score 0):

As for today, in Play Store - My Apps, there is an **ALL** tab that shows us every downloaded application

Answer (score -3):

No, There is not any such facilities yet.